# How to get all fields related to a specific record type of an object in SOQL

Tags: apex

We have a rest api call where id is passed needs to be cloned in order to get a new record for the object. As the object has multiple record types, so we want to get fields based on the record type. **Is it possible to get fields based on record type of an object?**
The purpose of getting those fields were we do not need to fill few fields while cloning the record.

For example
RecordType A has following fields
FieldName1
FieldName2
FieldName3
FieldName4

RecordType B has following fields
FieldName1
FieldName3
FieldName5

While cloning the record we do not want to copy the FieldName3,FieldName4 value for RecordType A and similarly do not want to copy FieldName3 value for RecordType B.

If I use standard Clone(), then is it possible to avoid cloning few field values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fields aren't bound to Record Types. Fields may or may not appear on the _Page Layout_ for a specific Record Type, and fields may appear on the page layouts for many record types. Further, fields that are not on the page layout for a given record type may still be populated. So long story short: are you really sure you want to do it this way? What do you gain by doing so?

Comment: If you do, you'll probably want to call the UI API or the Apex Metadata API to inspect the layout.